# getting same id for every element

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am working on calendar where on clicking on a date i should see a list but on clicking I am seeing all the list due to ng-repeat and I have given dynamic class and id to dates,rows and lists which is reflecting fine in html but on using jquery attr('class') its showing same for all the dates,rows and lists

As you can see on printing the class its printing same class day0 for every element but in on inspecting the element its showing different classes day0 and day1

[image]

**template -**

```
<div ng-controller="calendarCtrl">
<div id="w{{$index}}" class="row weeks" ng-repeat="week in weeks" ng-controller="calendarCtrl">
    <div style="display:flex;" class="col" id="r{{$index}}">
        <span id="{{day.number}}" class="day {{'day' + day.number}} col" ng-class="{today: day.isToday,'different-month': !day.isCurrentMonth, selected:day.date.isSame(selected)}" ng-click="select(day)"  ng-repeat="day in week.days">
            {{day.number}}      
        </span>
    </div>
    <!-- appointment list    -->
    <div ng-show="dateFlag" class="list listPos" id="l{{$index}}">
        <div class="item-divider">Appoitnments</div>
        <div class="item">1</div>
        <div class="item">2</div>
        <div class="item">3</div>
        <div class="item">4</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

**controller -**

```
 scope.select = function(day) {
     console.log(day);

     scope.selected = day.date;  
     scope.dateFlag = ! scope.dateFlag;

     jQuery(document).ready(function($){
         console.log($('.day').attr("class"));
     });                 
 };
```

Comment: There is no need for jquery in your controller at all. First your controller function will fire when the DOM is ready. Second you really should not manipulate the DOM in your controller, use a directive. Lastly to conditionally add a class use the native `ng-class` directive to do that job.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are iterating on `weeks` and appending `day.number` which has no relation with week. The value of `day.number` will be same in all the iterations.

If you want, you can append `$index` so that the class names will have suffix `$index`.

Comment: I used $index also but its still showing the first index if you'll see in the code I have used it for secod div id i.e. w{{$index}} but if I am calling parent id for span then again its getting w0 for every element but on inspecting element its showing all right, main problem is with dynamic calling or displaying the id

Comment: Use $index on span. like **<span id="{{day.number+$index}}" class="day {{'day' + $index}} col" ng-class....**